# How can i refresh the page that i am currently in from a function call php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After the user hits the follow/unfollow button the same button appears (because the page is not refresh, and if the user clicks on the button again an error will pop since the user is trying to access a duplicate field) However i want the page to refresh after any of the buttons are clicked this is the code i have for both the php and the functions used:

```
            function unfollow($userid, $uploader_id){

        if(isset($_POST['unfollow'])){
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
            $userid = sanitize($userid);
            $uploader_id = sanitize($uploader_id);
            //prepare statement
            $stmt = $con ->prepare("DELETE FROM follow
    WHERE u_id = ? AND uploader_id = ?");
            $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$userid, $uploader_id);
            if($result = $stmt->execute()){
                header("Refresh:0");
                echo "<h1 style='clear:left;font-size:15px; color:blue;'>UnFollowed</h1>";  
            }
        }
        }


function follow($userid, $uploader_id){

 if(isset($_POST['follow']))
{
if(logged_in()){

if($userid != $uploader_id){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
    $userid = sanitize($userid);
    $uploader_id = sanitize($uploader_id);
    //prepare statement
     $stmt = $con ->prepare("INSERT INTO follow (u_id, uploader_id) VALUES    (?, ?)");
     $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$userid, $uploader_id);
        if($result = $stmt->execute()){ 
        header("Refresh:1");
            echo "<h1 style='clear:left;font-size:15px; color:blue;'>Followed</h1>";    
        }

         else{
            echo "Failed to follow";    
        }
    }// users cant follow themselves


   }//if not logged in do this
   else{
      echo "<h1 style='clear:left;font-size:15px; color:red;'>You have to be logged in to follow</h1>"; 
       }
   }
}
```

I am using it in the following format in php:

```
    <?php

   //if the user is not logged in just display a button that send                  him/her to the login page if clicked 

    if(!logged_in()){
    ?>
     <form id="follow" style="clear:left;" action="">

     <button id="follow_btn" type="submit">Follow</button>

     </form>

   <?php 
    }

 //if the user is not following the uploader show the follow button

    else if(!is_following($session_user_id, $uploaderid)){

    ?>

   <form id="follow" method="POST" style="clear:left;" action="<?php                    follow($session_user_id, $uploaderid) ?>">

   <button id="follow_btn" type="submit" name="follow">Follow</button>

   </form>
   <?php 

  //else show the unfollow button
   }else{
    ?>
   <form id="follow" method="POST" style="clear:left;" action="<?php     unfollow($session_user_id, $uploaderid) ?>">
    <button id="follow_btn" type="submit" name="unfollow">UnFollow</button>
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I am first checking if the user is not logged in, in that case just show a follow button that doesnt do a thing. Else if he is logged in but is not following the uploader then show the follow button. Else if the user is following show the unfollow button.

Comment: What is `sanitize` doing here, and what function does that perform?

Comment: sanitize is a function that uses mysqli_real_escape_string, however i have changed my question since i have found a solution myself. I do appreciate ur help tho.

Comment: Since you're using placeholder values, which is great, you don't need to "sanitize" anything. That leads to double-escaping which is a huge problem. Let the driver do the work for you.